# Car horn only works during morning period

Tags: nissan, horn

My car's horn only works during the morning in transit to work. After the engine and the weather heats up, i need to apply force to the horn in order for it to work. During the midday sun, it doesn't work at all. What is the source of the issue? What are some potential fixes?

Car: Nissan Note 2006 (JDM)

Comment: Do you hear the horn relay click when you press the horn button when the horn doesn't blow?

Comment: What car? Year? Model? Where is the horn switch? Is it getting too hot and some plastic expanding creaing an insulating barrier?

Comment: @solarmike added car details in description

Comment: @paulster2 no, there is no relay click

Comment: A relay wouldn't make it hard to push the horn activator down.

Comment: The problem would be on the steering wheel, try putting the horn wire directly to the ground if it always work than it is just the button "the part removed" else it could be the ribbon cable is getting worn out.  https://youtu.be/lKb1XCMtvhA

Answer (score 0):

Weather can make old circuits behave in a ghastly way. I myself experimented a faulty A/C clutch coil during a cold spell (it showed the signs of a false contact since it intermittently lost continuity at the terminals), that apparently fixed itself when warmer and more humid weather came back (in the meanwhile, i've bought a spare coil just in case it fails definitely). The "i need to apply force" part, provided you're referring to the switch in the steering wheel, likely means that the problem isn't in the relay, but in the switch you're actually pressing. Try disassembling it and checking for any oxidation or false contact.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to press the horn harder when the vehicle has been warmed by the sun then the issue must relate to the plastic trim around the horn push expanding and becoming resistant to pushing.

My first guess at the way to fix it would be to remove the plastic trim covering the horn push and applying white silicone spray grease to the rear face of the plastic in the parts it clips into and if applicable, moves down (sometimes you find tubes or slots behind horn pushes intended to guide the plastic along).